# salesforce bug? <apex:facet> doesn't render within <apex:repeat>

Tags: apex, visualforce, datatable, repeat, facet

I am having to plot matrix type chart where I have dynamic data.

Here is the code

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!lstTableRows}" var="rows">
     <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">{!rows.header1}</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!rows.inputValue}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:repeat value="{!rows.lstOfTargetValues}" var="targetValue">                   
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">{!targetValue.header}</apex:facet>
            <apex:inputText value="{!targetValue.inputValue}" html-placeholder="enter the input"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:dataTable>
```

In this case the header from `facet` element will not render. It renders fine when it is outside the `<apex:repeat>`.

**NOTE**: the above code is within `<apex:dataTable>`

Am I missing anything here or this is a bug. I would love to hear of any workaround with this.

Comment: That's not a bug. Look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_facet.htm). "An <apex:facet> component can only exist in the body of a parent component if the parent supports facets."

Comment: [<apex:facet>](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_facet.htm) is not a child component of <apex:repeat>. Remeber, repeat tag is not required inside a <apex:pageBlockTable> component. You can use <apex:dataTable> instead as this is a parent component of <apex:facet>.

Comment: The `<apex:repeat>` here is `child element of`  `<apex:dataTable>` and don't want to write this `code for all columns manually`, instead, render from a collection using `<apex:repeat>`

Comment: `<apex:dataTable>` does not require `<apex:repeat>`. Can you please post some more code snippet.

Comment: @SarojBera: I am basically having to creates `columns as well from a collection`. `dataTable` helps you creates `rows from collections`. Added more code for your reference.

Comment: can you use the `headerValue` attribute on `apex:column` ?

Comment: `headerValue` takes string literal only and can't use repeat variable